# Understanding ReusableBarrier Problem (from 'Little Book of Semaphores')

Tags: java, concurrency

The problem statement is as follows:

Often a set of cooperating threads will perform a series of steps in a loop and
synchronize at a barrier after each step. For this application we need a reusable
barrier that locks itself after all the threads have passed through.

Given Solution is:

```
1 # rendezvous
2
3 mutex.wait()
4     count += 1
5     if count == n:
6         turnstile2.wait() # lock the second
7         turnstile.signal() # unlock the first
8 mutex.signal()
9
10 turnstile.wait() # first turnstile
11 turnstile.signal()
12
13 # critical point
14
15 mutex.wait()
16     count -= 1
17     if count == 0:
18         turnstile.wait() # lock the first
19         turnstile2.signal() # unlock the second
20 mutex.signal()
21
22 turnstile2.wait() # second turnstile
23 turnstile2.signal()
```

Suppose we use this barrier for 2 threads and we pump 100 threads through this barrier. when second thread has unlocked turnstile(7) and reaches line 9, now, thread 3 come along and,
it increments count,
count > n so it releases mutex,
since turnstile is unlocked it reaches critical point also,
similarly, thread 4, thread 5, thread 6 can execute critical point, executing it more than 2 times.
what is stopping them from passing through the barrier ahead of thread 2? Or is my understanding wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement indicates (page 22):

> You can assume that there are n threads and that this value is stored in a
>   variable, n, that is accessible from all threads.

So if n=2 and there are 100 threads, you have violated this assumption and the solution will not work.

Comment: In this case we are setting up barrier to expect 2 threads, that is it should let two threads through when second arrives, and it should block third one until fourth one arrives. so if we pump 100 threads through it, it should allow threads in pairs to go through it.
However in above example, i think it will break and let all threads through if 2nd thread sleeps at line number 9.

Comment: Also, After a discussion on concurrency-interest mailing list, it seems The expectation, in the book examples, is that the barrier is used in a loop by the same set of N threads. It isn't a general purpose barrier that can be used by multiple sets of N threads...

Comment: Right.  It sounds like what you have in mind is a barrier that allows threads into the critical section in batches of three only, and requires the three to exit before admitting the next three.  In that case I think you'll enjoy Chapter 5.  There are several problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this goes beyond the question, but here goes: the listed solution is as far as I can tell correct as long as at most n threads are inside the barrier code.  One way of guaranteeing this is to only have n threads in total.

The book also presents a different way of ensuring that only n threads are inside a given region: the Multiplex (using a Semaphore to guarantee that at most n threads use a given resource at a time). Use it like this:

```
general_barrier.init(n):
    occupancy = Semaphore(n)
    barrier = Barrier(n)
general_barrier.enter():
    occupancy.wait()
    barrier.enter()
    barrier.leave()
general_barrier.leave():
    occupancy.signal()
```

You would use it like this:

```
shared state:
    gbarrier = general_barrier(n)
each of m threads (where m > n, but in particular try m > 2*n):
    while True:
        gbarrier.enter()
        something critical
        gbarrier.leave()
```

In the code in the question, you could put `occupancy.wait()` on line 2 and `occupancy.signal()` on line 24, and have basically this solution.  Note that the code in the question puts the equivalent of `barrier.leave()` after the critical point, i.e. in `general_barrier.leave()`, rather than before as I have done it.  I don't think this matters for correctness, though it may matter in regards to the number of context switches performed.  Maybe, in some situations.  Reader discretion is advised ;-)